# With a table of visitor data, how do I get hourly totals of total and unique visitors?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Visits table, structured like the below:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| ID | Date       | Time     | Session |
+--------------------------------------+
| 1  | 05-18-2014 | 20:15:10 | 1       |
| 2  | 05-18-2014 | 20:15:20 | 1       |
| 3  | 05-18-2014 | 21:40:20 | 2       |
| 4  | 05-18-2014 | 21:45:30 | 1       |
| 5  | 05-18-2014 | 21:50:50 | 3       |
+--------------------------------------+
```

The session column is the user's session ID. I would like to query the table to get the hourly total and unique visitors, to get a result like:

```
+-----------------------+
| Time | Total | Unique |
+-----------------------+
| 20   | 2     | 1      |
| 21   | 3     | 2      |
+-----------------------+
```

Unique visitors are visitors with sessions that have *never* been seen before, anywhere in the Visits table.

The below only selects unique visitors inside each hour:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) Total, COUNT(DISTINCT Session) Unique, HOUR(Time) Time
WHERE Date = '05-18-2014'
FROM Visits
GROUP BY HOUR(Time)
```

The following seems to work, however requires two queries, and a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) Total, HOUR(Time) Time
FROM Visits
GROUP BY HOUR(Time);

SELECT COUNT(*) Unique, HOUR(Time) Time
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Visits
    GROUP BY Session
    ORDER BY Date, Time DESC
) UniqueVisits
WHERE Date = '05-18-2014'
GROUP BY HOUR(Time);
```

Is there a simpler way to get the two totals?

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the desired results for the sample data?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Added.

Comment: That was how I interpreted the question.  My answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by "distinct" you mean that you only want one session counted once (during the first hour).  If so, you can do this:

```
select max(h.total) as total, count(firstvisit.session) as Firsts, h.hr
from (select hour(time) as hr, count(*) as total
      from visits v
      where Date = '05-18-2014'
      group by hour(time)
     ) h left outer join
     (select session, min(hour(time))as hr
      from visits v
      where Date = '05-18-2014'
      group by session
     ) firstvisit
     on h.hr = firstvisit.hr
GROUP BY h.hr;
```

Comment: +1, I tried to avoid the join on the `min(hour(time))` calculated expression, but we couldn't save it, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be very slightly faster than my sub-query solution, taking around a second for 500k rows on my server. Is there any way to optimise this further?

Comment: @AlanEdwardes . . . Do you have an index on `visits(date, time, session)`?